# Calling tf.session.run gets slower

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I am having trouble with my performance doing nlp tasks. I want to use [this](https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128-with-normalization/1) module for word embeddings and it produces output, but its runtime increases with each iterative call. I have already read about different solutions, but i cant get them to work. I suspect using [tf.placeholders](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) would be the a good solution, but i dont know how to use them in this instance.

Example code for my problem:

```py
embedder = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128-with-normalization/1")
session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
session.run(tf.tables_initializer())

doc = [["Example1", "Example2", "Example3", "Example4", ...], [...], ...]

for paragraph in doc:
   vectors = session.run(embedder(paragraph))
   #do something with vectors
```

Note, that doc cant be fed to the embedder all at once.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are recreating the whole model on each iteration, so the TensorFlow graph is growing constantly. You should instead have a single model with a placeholder for your input, then feed the different paragraphs.

```
embedder = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128-with-normalization/1")
session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
session.run(tf.tables_initializer())

doc = [["Example1", "Example2", "Example3", "Example4", ...], [...], ...]

my_input = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [None])
my_embedder = embedder(my_input)
for paragraph in doc:
   vectors = session.run(my_embedder, feed_dict={my_input: paragraph})
   #do something with vectors
```

Comment: Thank you very much i have read, that this was the problem, but i was not sure how to approach it with placeholders.